# How to parse the dynamic JSON to JavaBean

Tags: java, json

The JSON returned normally is like this

```
{"1":0.5}
```

However sometimes will return with mutipule key-value like

```
{
   "1":0.5,
   "2":0.5,
   "3":0.5
}
```

The content of JSON is dynamic. How to define the JavaBean to parse the JSON currectly.
I parse the JSON using fastjson.
Thanks for your kindly answering.

Comment: Please provide some code and explain what you tried to do and what isn't working. Read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried using a HashMap? I don't use fastjson personally so I don't know, but for Gson that should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Map<K, V>` for that and the Fastjson [documentation](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson/wiki/TypeReference) provides an example on how to do it:

```java
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> parseToMap(String json, Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
    return JSON.parseObject(json, new TypeReference<Map<K, V>>(keyType, valueType) {});
}
```

Then use:

```java
String json = ...
Map<String, BigDecimal> map = parseToMap(json, String.class, BigDecimal.class);
```

Comment: 3Q for your answering, that's just what I need